# C++ if statement over 4 digits

Tags: c++

im writing a program to convert a four digit octal number to a decimal number. I have to do this programs using charactes. **no char rays or strings says my lecturer**. does anybody no how i can do this? here is my code:

```
int main() {

  char a = 0;
  char b = 0;
  char c = 0;
  char d = 0;

  cout << "Enter 4 digit octal number ";
  cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
  if (a - '0' > 7 || b - '0' > 7 || c - '0' > 7 || d - '0' > 7 || !isdigit(a)
      || !isdigit(b) || !isdigit(c) || !isdigit(d)) {
    cout << "Bad data";
  }
  else
    cout << "Decimal form of that number: " << ((a - '0') * 512) + ((b - '0')
        * 64) + ((c - '0') * 8) + (d - '0') << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Which part of it does not work as you expect? What exactly do you expect?

Comment: You've already done it. What is it that you find unclear/confusing?

Comment: sorry i should have been more clear. I have to make it to say "bad data" of the user enters a number in more than 4 integers.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I supplied `isdigit` as

```
bool isdigit(char digit) {
  return digit >= '0' && digit <='9';
}
```

and simplified the first check to

```
if (!isdigit(a) || !isdigit(b) || !isdigit(c) || !isdigit(d)) {
  cout << "Bad data";
} else ...
```

Comment: The first part of the `if` is needed to ensure that `8` or `9` isn't entered, as they are not valid octal digits.

Comment: isdigit is part of C99 was provided in 4.3BSD for a long time before that, so it's probable the originating poster didn't realise that it's not completely portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cin.peek()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/peek/) to check the next unread character after reading `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. If it is octal digit, then input is wrong, otherwise (even if it fails) all ok.